# When running feature specs, how do you get the rails application output to log to a console?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec-rails

When running feature specs for my application, all of the sudden each test is timing out.  I'd love to be able to temporarily output the Rails application output to the console to see where the bottleneck is.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this in a separate terminal window:

```
$ tail -f log/test.log
```

and then run the tests.